# ASP.net State Server losing session in load balanced environment

Tags: asp.net, stateserver

I am aware that this is a commonly asked question but I have yet to find anything that answers my question. I am randomly losing session data in a load balanced environment. I have done the following:

- Set all the servers to the same state server
- Ensured that all the machineKeys in the web.config are the same
- Ensured that all the machineKeys in the machine.config are the same
- Ensured that all the paths to the web service files are the same (case sensitive)
- Made sure that the services all have the same ID

The session simply will not persist over multiple web servers. The following is the web.config session information:

```
    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=[ipAddress]:42424" stateNetworkTimeout="30" timeout="60" />
```

Any ideas? I am out of them. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. This is going over ssl (https).

Answer (score 0):

I've been told it's not possible to persist session data in a multi-server environment unless you use a SQL Server instance to store it...I'm assuming you're familiar with it but here's a link for others who may not be:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Comment: Yes SQL is an option but state server is another option. The ASP State Service is an out of process caching service that allows you to load balance multiple servers on the same session.